# fork() leaking? Taking longer and longer to fork a simple process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, fork

I have a system in which two identical processes are run (let's call them replicas). When signaled, a replica will duplicate itself by using the `fork()` call. A third process selects one of the processes to kill randomly, and then signals the other to create a replacement. Functionally, the system works well; it can kill / respawn replicas all day except for the performance issue.

The `fork()` call is taking longer and longer. The following is the simplest setup that still displays the problem. The timing be is displayed in the graph below: [image: fork timing]

The replica's code is the following:

```
void restartHandler(int signo) {
// fork
  timestamp_t last = generate_timestamp();
  pid_t currentPID = fork();


  if (currentPID >= 0) { // Successful fork
    if (currentPID == 0) { // Child process
      timestamp_t current = generate_timestamp();
      printf("%lld\n", current - last);

      // unblock the signal
      sigset_t signal_set;
      sigemptyset(&signal_set);
      sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGUSR1);
      sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &signal_set, NULL);

      return;
    } else {   // Parent just returns
      waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
      return;
    }
  } else {
    printf("Fork error!\n");
    return;
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  if (signal(SIGUSR1, restartHandler) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("Failed to register the restart handler");
    return -1;
  }

  while(1) {
    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The longer the system runs, the worse it gets.

Sorry to lack a specific question, but does anyone have any idea / clues as to what is going on? It seems to me that there is a resource leak in the kernel (thus the linux-kernel tag), but I don't know where where to start looking.

What I have tried:

- Tried [kmemleak](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kmemleak.txt), which did not catch anything. This implies that if there is some memory "leak" that it is still reachable.
- `/proc/<pid>/maps` is not growing.
- Currently running the 3.14 kernel with RT patch (note this happens with non-rt and rt processes), and have also tried on 3.2.
- zombie processes are not an issue. I have tried a version in which I setup another process as a subreaper using [prctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html)
- I first noticed this slowdown in a system in which the timing measurements are being down outside of the restarted process; same behavior.

Any hints? Anything I can provide to help? Thanks!

Comment: The child is only an exact copy until the time the new process starts executing, or rather, until the first store instruction. Afterwards, the memory has to start making copy-on-write copies.

Comment: In the full system I get around this by using mlockall and then walking /proc/pid/maps doing dummy writes. In both the full system and the code I provide here, the performance problem with fork remains.

Comment: Have you used the ps command to see what is running (usually the 'top' utility does this repeatedly for you) and how much time is being spent in each running process?   In your code, I do not see any passing of the user1 signal so it is doubtful that any of the child processes are being killed

Comment: Can you try using vfork or clone instead of Fork - the graph you posted is well known behaviour of posix fork (i.e. the greater the fork count the slower performance) this is because everytime you fork it copies the page table.

See this table from the excellent book "The Linux programming interface"

http://books.google.com.au/books?id=2SAQAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA610&dq=28.3+Speed&hl=en&sa=X&ei=10uGVO-sLcv98QXjioGgBA&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=28.3%20Speed&f=false

Comment: @user3629249 There is a separate process that sends `kill -9` to one of the replicas, and `kill -s USR1` to the other.

Comment: @Matt Looking at vfork... I am not calling `exec` afterwards, and I actually want the data from the parent to be copied over. As for performance, do you have a source (I'll try to find the book you recommended tomorrow)? The performance problem I am seeing is not related to the parent size, and the number of running processes is also steady (since I kill a process for every new one I fork). Thanks!

Comment: No sure if google book link works for you (for me it shows the relevant excerpt-which shows performance of forking 1000 times for each method -both with and without a subsequent exec).

Comment: Thinking some more are you using exit() to terminate (I only see a return 0) I know you can use cleanup handlers after an exit() call but am not familiar with this myself- first thing I'd try is adding an exit(0); or similar if not there already.

Comment: @Matt, There is no call to `exit` because the process is being killed by another process. The table in the book link does not show the behavior I am seeing: fork getting slower over time.

Comment: It's hard to know from the snippet you posted I'm only throwing ideas out there as to why you are seeing the behaviour you are getting. ("A third process selects one of the processes to kill randomly, and then signals the other to create a replacement") How are you killing the process? (are you using SIGTERM?), is it leaving behind resources when it gets killed without seeing that part of the code its hard to tell. You suspect a kernel leak but its probably more likely the leak is in your own program.

Comment: Saw you earlier comment (I wish I could edit posts instead of having to make a new one each time...) "There is a separate process that sends kill -9 to one of the replicas". Again without knowing for sure I suspect this could cause problems SIGKILL (kill-9) is the blunt hammer approach sigterm gives you more scope for exiting gracefully (with cleanup handlers) so maybe theres something there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66524/discussion-between-superdesk-and-matt).

Comment: The docs say that signal handlers are inherited by the child process, so why do you subscribe to it again in the child process? Isn't that the root of all evil?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit You are right, there is no need to re-subscribe (removed that from the code). The worsening performance remains. The signal does need to be unblocked every time.

Comment: Since you have WNOHANG in your waitpid() call, you are likely to end up with a lot of zombie processes. Can you fix the program so child processes are properly disposed of and re-run the test ?

Comment: @nos Zombie processes are not a problem. When the program presented is run, I see only the occasional zombie, and these do not accumulate because they are reaped by init. I have tested more thoroughly in a more complicated setup by having another process set as the reaper to make sure that all zombies are taken care of.

Comment: for what it's worth printf() is not alloed inside signal handlers, write() however is allowed.  see the signal(7) manpage.

Comment: Um ... In you own graph you clearly show that the call is NOT takin "longer and longer", in fact the behaviour appears to be highly deterministic, the allocation time rises and falls very predictably, thats a pretty good example of determinism, im guessing one could even create an equation for this algorithm

Comment: Signals are not very reliable in terms of delivery, so might endup killing unreliably or having more parents sitting int waitoid(). Try using 
 struct sigaction action;
 action.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
 action.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT;
 sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, NULL);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slowdown is caused by an accumulation of anonymous vmas, and is a known problem. The problem is evident when there are a large number of `fork()` calls and the parent exits before the children. The following code recreates the problem ([source Daniel Forrest](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/8/15/765)):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pid_t pid;
  while (1) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
      /* error */
      return 1;
    }
    if (pid) {
      /* parent */
      sleep(2);
      break;
    }
    else {
      /* child */
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The behavior can be confirmed by checking `anon_vma` in `/proc/slabinfo`.

There is a patch ([source](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/6/3/568)) which limits the length of copied `anon_vma_chain` to five. I can confirm that the patch fixes the problem.

As for how I eventually found the problem, I finally just started putting `printk` calls throughout the `fork` code, checking the times shown in `dmesg`. Eventually I saw that it was the call to `anon_vma_fork` which was taking longer and longer. Then it was a quick matter of google searching.

It took a rather long time, so I would still appreciate any suggestions for a better way to have gone about tracking down the problem. And to all of those that already spent time trying to assist me, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using the generic wait() call, rather than waitpid()? It's just a guess, but I heard it was better from a professor in undergrad. Also, have you tried using [address sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/)

Also, you can use GDB to debug a child process as well (if you haven't already tried that). You can use follow-fork-mode:

```
set follow-fork-mode child
```

but that is only capable of debugging the parent. You can debug both by getting the pid of the child process, calling sleep() after forking then:

```
attach <child process pid>
```

then call:

```
detach
```

This is useful because you can dump memory leaks into valgrind. Just call valgrind with

```
valgrind --vgdb-error=0...<executable>
```

then set some relevant breakpoints, and continue through your program until you hit your breakpoints then search for leaks:

```
monitor leak_check full reachable any
```

then:

```
monitor block_list <loss_record_nr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: maybe it is related to MMU or cache? As far as I understand, upon fork(), kernel fills appropriate table entries with references to the same physical RAM pages. You wrote, You are doing dummy writes, but are You doing them to executable segmens (if yes, how, because these should be write-protected)? From the graph it seems performance increaes at some points ( 512? 512*3? 512*4? ). It makes me suspect system (kernel?, hardware?) is aware of the problem and uses some workaround (duplicate antries at MMU for the same physical page? some data structure is split?).